# how to make changes in another Database

Tags: oracle, data-migration

We have some hundreds of tables that contain thousands of records in an Oracle database. Now we are going to install a cloud database for Oracle which will contain all the tables in Oracle. Now if we do any changes in that Oracle DB, same should be reflected in the cloud DB. For example, if I insert or delete records in table x in Oracle DB, the same should be done in cloud table.

I know trigger is one of the options but it wont help us as we have to create one trigger for each table. Help me to get this done in short and better way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How much control do you have over the "cloud database"?  Can you configure Streams and/or GoldenGate to replicate the data?

Comment: am not on that part of configuration or installation with cloud,but my part is to write triggers for all that tables in one oracle db that is going to affect the table in cloud db. so i just want some idea or technique to do it in real efficient way. Is there any way to get around this

Comment: @BALA whenever a dml operation is done in source table that should be done in that table in cloud db

Comment: See [this page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/data-integration/index.html) for information on Oracle data replication.  In particular, it gives a basic explanation of what GoldenGate and Streams are.  IMO writing hundreds of triggers to do this is not a manageable approach.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Oracle streams is the right solution for me.

Comment: I have a doubt about using streams. will the processing time for applying the changes in target db is instant or will it take time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to get a list of all the tables and make triggers automatically there are a number of dba tables that have them in there - have a look at dba_tables (or all_tables depending on what access you have). You can make a script easily enough to automatically create a script for the triggers if that's what you're after.

If you're database has any sort of high transaction rates though I'd probably avoid this and look at another solution, something like shareplex or so on. If you're after a slave database (just copied from the source database) oracle replication may do what you want, if your cloud database is oracle as well.